# How to check if an integer is within a range of numbers, where that range has a stepping other than one

Tags: vb.net

It is easy to check if a value is within a range of values. `min <= value && value<=max`
This assumes the range of values is continuous, how do we check if the range has a stepping.
eg. `0 3 6 9 12`  is `min:=0, max:=12, stepping: 3`
values of `3` `6` would return true, but `1` `4` would return false.

What about a descending range?
'min: 5, max: -5, stepping:= -3' would allow values `5 2 -1 -4`.

```
Function IsWithinSteppedRange( value As Integer,
                               min as Integer,
                               max As Integer,
                               stepping As Integer
                             ) As Boolean
' Is within bounds andalso has correct stepping
Return ((min <= value) And (value <= max)) AndAlso
       (Math.DivRem(min, stepping).Remainder = Math.DivRem(value, stepping).Remainder )
End Function
```

`
[System.Math.DivRem (.net 6.0 preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=net-6.0#System_Math_DivRem_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

The following code does the job, but potentially slow.

```
Function IsWithinSteppedRange(value as integer, startAt as integer, endAt as integer, stepping as integer) as Boolean
    For idx As Integer = startAt To endAt Step stepping
        If idx = value Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End function
```

Comment: First off if you can have negative stepping values then I'd suggest changing the names to start/stop instead of min/max.  Then you'd need to do `end <= value && value <= start` when `stepping` is negative.  And you want the equivalent of `(value - start) % stepping == 0` which in VB is I guess `Maths.DivRem(value-starte, setpping).Remainder == 0`?

Comment: @juharr See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

I've included some checking of the values and that they all tally up with each other. As I commented in the code feel free to add your own error handling.

The way I've worked is to swap the min and max values if the min is greater the max value. This will allow for increasing and decreasing ranges

Then, to allow for when the min and max values aren't multiples of the stepping value, is to find the offset of the new min value from 0 and subtract it from the min and max values when checking the modulus for example, the following range..

min=1 max=17 stepping=4

So any of these numbers should produce a True result

1 5 9 13 17

If we try to calculate the modulus 4 of these numbers, they would all fail.

However, if we work out the offset from 0 of the min value and subtract that from the input value, any numbers you send to the function will have the correct value for calculating MOD 4..

0 4 8 12 16

I've only done some manual testing and it seems to work with increasing ranges, decreasing ranges, and seems to catch any ranges that don't match the stepping.. for example min=0 max=10 stepping =3

I think it works :-)

```
    Function IsWithinSteppedRange(value As Integer,
                           min As Integer,
                           max As Integer,
                           stepping As Integer
                         ) As Boolean

    'check stepping isn't zero
    If stepping = 0 Then
        'add your own exception handling here instead of msgbox
        MessageBox.Show("Stepping value cannot be zero" & vbCrLf & "Returning False")
        Return False
    End If

    'if the range is decreasing the swap min and max for cleaner code
    If max < min Then
        Dim tempSwap As Integer
        tempSwap = min
        min = max
        max = tempSwap
    End If

    'get offset of min from 0
    Dim offsetToZero As Integer = 0 - min

    'check if stepping is correct for range
    If Not ((min + offsetToZero) Mod Math.Abs(stepping) = 0 And (max + offsetToZero) Mod Math.Abs(stepping) = 0) Then
        'add your own exception handling here instead of msgbox
        MessageBox.Show("Max or Min values dont both match stepping")
    End If

    'final check for number in range equal to a step
    If value >= min And value <= max And (value + offsetToZero) Mod stepping = 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 Function IsWithinSteppedRange(value As Integer, startAt As Integer, endAt As Integer, stepping As Integer) As Boolean
    If value > Math.Max(startAt, endAt) OrElse value < Math.Min(startAt, endAt) Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return (value Mod stepping = 0)
    End If
End Function
```